# best NoSQL for inverted index

Tags: nosql

I'm working on a small project where I need to build an inverted index and apply similarity algorithms based on a user query - basic information retrieval. What's the best NoSQL product for building and searching inverted indices?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1):

Since an inverted index is all about storing the relationship between words and their locations within a document, I'm not sure this is really a good use case for NoSQL.  Traditional SQL will work better here.  For example, try a data structure like this:

```
Documents (DocumentID primary key, DocumentText text)
Words (WordID primary key, Word text)
Instances (InstanceID primary key, WordID foreign key, DocumentID foreign key, WordIndex integer)
```

With this structure, as you insert a document into the `Documents` table, you parse out each word and add it to the `Words` table if it's new or retrieve the existing `WordID` if it already exists, and then add the associated data to the `Instances` table.

If you're intent on using NoSQL you can use it with something like MongoDB and put all your documents in one collection and all the words in another collection.  Inside each `Word` document, include an `Instances` array which would be an array of objects with the `ObjectID` of the associated document and the word index in that document.  However, I'm not sure if MongoDB is optimized for handling such large arrays within documents.  Common words like 'a' and 'the' could end up going over the 4MB document limit even, depending on how much data you have.

Answer (score 1):

see [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/)

> - Distributed, scalable, and highly available
> - Real-time search and analytics capabilities
> - Sophisticated RESTful API